# </stack => </stackengine> autocomplete in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

When I edit an aspx file in Visual Studio 2008 and enter `</script>`, it is autocorrected to `</scriptengine>` when I press the `>` key. So, when I enter `</script>`, it comes out as `</scriptengine>` in the document. Is there an option to prevent this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to check`Show all settings` at the bottom of the page under `Tools`, `Options`, `Text Editor`. Then you can see the appropriate HTML options, specifically `Auto list members`.